# Html form having more than one file input not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms

Html code

```
<form action="projectOperations.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Upload 1 <input type="file" name="file1"><br>       
    Upload 2 <input type="file" name="file2">   <br>    
    Upload 3 <input type="file" name="file3">       <br>
    Upload 4 <input type="file" name="file4">       <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Php code for projectOperations.php

```
`var_dump($_POST);`
```

When i look into console that status still **pending**

[image]

I am using Amazon EC2 instance for this code.

Found two links on stack overflow relevant to this, but no solution found

[uploading files stuck on pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937299/uploading-files-stuck-on-pending)

[Form having more than one file input not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008082/form-having-more-than-one-file-input-not-submitted)

Can anyone help to understand the problem?

If it server problem what setting i have to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lots of debugging problem was identified as...

It was firewall of network, which was not allowing to upload multiple files.

When I tried to upload files from different network, it worked.
So it was not server or code problem.

Network administrator of the network can fix this error.